# How many enemies do I have to collect to use them in battle?

Tags: dragon-quest-heroes

In Dragon Quest Heroes: Rocket Slime, you can "collect" various enemies by placing them on the carts that you use to take items (and yourself) out of an area.

If you collect enough of a certain enemy, they can become a part of your tank fighting team. How many of each do I have to collect for this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this walkthrough](http://faqs.ign.com/articles/736/736337p1.html), collecting enemies first lets you add them to your crew, then you get a silver statue, and if you collect a hundred of them, you get a gold statue:

> Q: Why do I have to collect many monsters?
>   A: 30 earns you a
>   crewmember, 50 a silver statue, 100 a golden statue in the    museum.
>   Silver statues do not do anything special, only for    pleasure, while
>   all golden ones unlock the final Tank Masters battles.    You can also
>   unlock these battles by completing the main storyline.